# Problem with local variable in a Python function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying writing a function in Python 3.6 to get a list of LVM, their Volume Group and size in a linux machine.
This is the code i wrote

```
def get_attribute():
command = subprocess.Popen("lvs --rows", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in command.stdout:
    line_cod = line.decode("utf-8")
    if "LV" in line_cod:
        lvm_list = (line_cod.split()[1:])
    elif "VG" in line_cod:
        vg_list = line_cod.split()[1:]
    elif "LSize"in line_cod:
        size_list = line_cod.split()[1:]
        lvdata = zip(lvm_list, vg_list, size_list)
        return lvdata
```

This return an iterable i can loop to in order to have a tuple with LVM name, VolumeGroup and Size.
Although this works fine, on Pycharm after `zip` gives me a warning about the `lvm_list` and `vg_list` variables : `local variable "lvm_list/vg_list might be referenced before assignment`. 
Searching on the web I understood that this error has to do with variable scopes but I knew that `if` statements don't define a scope in Python.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your solution works if and only if there are always two lines, one with the `LV` data and one with the `VG` data, before the line with the `LSize` data. This might be the case, but the linter doesn't know that and all it sees is that there are cases in the `if` construct which cause the two variables `lvm_list` and `vg_list` to be read before they are assigned.

If you are sure that the `LSize` line always comes after the other two lines, you can initialize the variables before the loop with any value and the linter will stop complaining:

```py
def get_attribute():
command = subprocess.Popen("lvs --rows", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lvm_list = None
vg_list = None
for line in command.stdout:
    line_cod = line.decode("utf-8")
    if "LV" in line_cod:
        lvm_list = (line_cod.split()[1:])
    elif "VG" in line_cod:
        vg_list = line_cod.split()[1:]
    elif "LSize"in line_cod:
        size_list = line_cod.split()[1:]
        lvdata = zip(lvm_list, vg_list, size_list)
        return lvdata
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer now i understood why Pycharm was complaining.

Comment: @etienne-ott note that it's pycharm's linter that complains here, not the Python runtime.

Comment: Also I would not consider silencing the linter this way as a proper, production-grade solution. If the case ever append that your process enter the last `elif` branche before having collected a proper `lvm_list` and `vg_list`, then the call to `zip()` will crash with a `TypeError` (`None` is not iterable), which is hardly better than dying from an `UnboundLocalError`.  You may actually want to check `lvm_list` and `vg_list` at this point and raise your own custom exception type for this condition (so the caller code knows what failed and can take appropriate action).